# Draw a one pixel line around square sprite

Tags: c#, xna

I have a 15 x 15 pixel box, that I draw several off in different colours using:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, colour);
```

What I'd like to do is draw a one pixel line around the outside, in different colours, thus making it a 17 x 17 box, with (for example), a blue outline one pixel wide and a grey middle.

The only way I can think of doing it is to draw two boxes, one 17x17 in the outline colour, one 15x15 with the box colour, and layer them to give the appearance of an outline:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture17by17, position, outlineColour);
spriteBatch.Draw(texture15by15, position, boxColour);
```

Obviously the position vector would need to be modified but I think that gives a clear picture of the idea.

The question is: is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw lines and triangles using `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives`, see [Drawing 3D Primitives using Lists or Strips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414.aspx) on MSDN for more details. Other figures like rectangles and circles are constructed from lines, but you'll need to implement them yourself.

To render lines in 2D, just use orthographic projection which mirrors transformation matrix from `SpriteBatch`.

You can find a more complete example with the `PrimitiveBatch` class which encapsulates the logic of drawing in the example [Primitives](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/primitives) from XBox Live Indie Games.

Comment: Thanks for this - it looks like two boxes layered will be more straight forward for what I'm looking to do, but this was exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Considering XNA can't draw "lines" like *OpenGL immediate mode* can, it is far *more efficient* to draw a *spite* with a **pre-generated texture quad** (2 triangles) than to draw additional geometry with *dynamic texturing* particularly when a single "line" each requiring 1 triangle;  **2 triangles vs 4** respectfully.  Less triangles and vertices in the former too.

So I would not try to draw a "thin" line using additional geometry that is trying to mimic lines around the outside of the other, instead continue with what you are doing - drawing 2 different sprites (each is a quad anyway)

> *Every object drawn in 3D is drawn using triangles.* - [Would you like to know more?](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/The_first_triangle.php)